# Error: homebrew/science was deprecated. What should I do?

Tags: homebrew

I got the following error when I tried to `brew tap homebrew/science`:  "Error: homebrew/science was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated." HOWEVER, there are no explicit instructions on what to do. All it's formulae were migrated to ____?

I am not new to science, but I am quite new to homebrew.

What should I do?.  I was going to use this to track the formulae for installation of `opencv` among other things.  I don't understand why something like `homebrew/science` would be depreciated or no longer relevant.

Comment: Most formulae were migrated to the core repository, so they will be available without *"tapping science"*. So, if you want package XYZ, just do `brew search XYZ` and you should find it.

Comment: Ok thanks for this info.  I am learning the ropes with the homebrew package system and almost every tutorial installation I go through has me tap homebrew/science.  I will try to search the packages directly.

Comment: That seems to have worked for opencv. In this case the package was migrated from homebrew/science to homebrew/core.  I guess if homebrew/science was dissolved then it's up to the package owner to decide where it gets migrated to (science2) etc.

Comment: If you're asking for a replacement for (or even the new location of) a 3rd-party library or package, that may or may not be "about programming", but it's *absolutely* in the "some questions are still off-topic" list in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic; see entry #4, re: "**Questions asking us to** recommend or **find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I disagree.  I had a legitimate question about a package management tool widely used for programming - a question that came up due to a specific issue I encountered.  
 I received an answer here on stackoverflow and now I understand a bit better about what happens when a giant collection such as homebrew/science disappears with an error message saying it has migrated but with no further information about where it has migrated to.  This was not a mere library but a collection of very important libraries pointed to by countless books and tutorials.

Comment: I apologize if it is not "savvy" enough of a quesiton but I hope that it helps someone else.

Comment: Whether something is "widely used for programming" is moot -- the question is whether it's "unique to software development" -- that is to say, whether its **exclusive** purpose is programming; `brew` is useful to nonprogrammers as well, and the answers certainly imply that the topic of this question is more `brew`-as-a-tool than `science`-as-a-collection. On which point -- there's a [very active `homebrew` tag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) on [apple.se]; future questions are likely to be more welcome there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most formulae were migrated to the core repository, so they will be available without *"tapping science"*.

So, if you want package XYZ, just do:

```
brew search XYZ
```

and you should find it.

Answer (score 14):

A quick solution is to use these command instead:

`brew tap brewsci/bio
brew tap brewsci/science`

Please see this [Github Issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/6365) for reference.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot! I was trying to install cdo using "brew install cdo" and couldn't get it to work. I'm using a Mac computer with macOS Mojave.

Comment: This solution works on macos monterey with apple M1

Answer (score 7):

If you cannot find your package by `brew search <package name>`,
you can give it a try to get it directly from the homebrew core.

Example:

```
brew install homebrew/science/hdf5
```

failed because homebrew/science was deprecated.

Solution:

```
brew install homebrew/core/hdf5
```

worked!

Answer (score 2):

Try to perform:

```
brew tap brewsci/science
```

Hope it helps